# Smart indenting after starting braces is not working

Tags: eclipse

I'm currently writing php-code in Eclipse 3.02 and a tiny but irritating bug/feature has popped up. When I change line after an opening curly brace `{` the marker always jumps to column 1, forcing me to manually tab to get the correct indentation. I have only experienced this whith opening curly braces. If I don't use open braces (i.e. press enter after `else`, `for` or closed curly brace `}`) it indents correctly. Is this a known error and is it solvable?

Comment: What formatter/code style are you using and which options are selected?

Comment: The formatter is set to Tabs.

Comment: I meant Eclipse Formatter (Window -> Preferences -> [Programming language you're using] -> Code Style -> Formatter)

Comment: Yes, and that's what I answered. The afformentioned path shows Formatting options "Tab policy", Indentation size", Default indentation for wrapped lines" and "Default indentation for array initializers".

Comment: Make sure you got *Statements within block* selected (and all other situations you want automatic indentation).

Comment: Can't find anything in the preferences  refering to Statements or the equivalent. I'll just have to go about tabbing then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you got *Statements within block* selected (and all other situations you want automatic indentation).

[image: Eclipse formatter options]

Comment: Sorry, but in my program there isn't anything that even remotely looks like what you are showing. And I can't find anything that refers to indentation.

Comment: Which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: 3.02 as i wrote in my first post.

Comment: I think it's the same for 3.0.2. This window is the active profile edition (click Edit)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23151/discussion-between-sandokan-and-m0skit0)